# Why does writing to HTTP stream pause for >100ms every few writes?

Tags: python, io, aiohttp, basehttprequesthandler

I am trying to stream MJPEG video over http using a multipart stream with aiohttp.

I have an implementation based on [this Gist by james4388](https://gist.github.com/james4388/fa59f3e7c9d4bac238c06b4327b88b46). I am trying to send a new JPEG image every 30ms or so currently. Timing the loop shows that the `await mpwriter.write(response, close_boundary=False)` often takes 0.3ms but every 3-5 times takes 150-200ms. This limits the maximum frame rate I can achieve and introduces latency into the stream which I am trying to avoid.

The loop used is

```python
while True:
        _, frame = wc.read()
        if frame is None:
            continue
        with MultipartWriter('image/jpeg', boundary=boundary) as mpwriter:
            result, encimg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)
            data = encimg.tostring()
            mpwriter.append(data, {
                'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
            })
            await mpwriter.write(response, close_boundary=False) # 'Pauses' here once every 3-5 times
        await response.drain()
```

I have also tried this using [BaseHttpServer](https://gist.github.com/walchko/0deed4152896e1940b0fe93c9eb4d061). This exhibits the same behaviour when calling `self.wfile.write(jpg.tostring())`.

I assume this pause happens when an underlying buffer is flushed out over the network, although I call `response.drain()` after each part. Each JPEG frame (so each part of the multi-part stream) is 441kB in size, so for 30fps I would be sending 13MB/s but currently I am achieving 5.3MB/s. This is on dedicated test LAN connection so I don't think bandwidth is an issue (Another appliance using MJPEG streaming achieves >15MB/s).

Making the image size smaller (e.g. with higher compression) increases the number of frames I can send before hitting the block, but the overall block is still there and my throughput is still only 4.3MB/s.

Comment: Is the application running on a Raspberry Pi device by any chance? Can you check CPU usage on it while the application is running? Also, what version of aiohttp are you using? AFAIK, drain is deprecated: `drain method is deprecated, use await resp.write()`

Comment: It ls running on a high spec desktop pc, so I don't thi k system resources in an issue. I will try use await resp. Write though, thanks.